# Qiskit: How can I modify Grover's algorithm to search for a state that doesn't belong to a basis set?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

Let's say I need to find the state $111$ in a "database" that is not the computational basis for a 3-qubits system (because it doesn't contain all of the basis vectors or contains the same vector more than one time). For example, this database could be the set $\{000, 010, 001, 000, 000, 110\}$.

How can I adjust Grover's algorithm for this kind of search? I would like a Qiskit implementation of this case.

Comment: Could be please a little bit clear? State 111 is not in the database, so it cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, I was considering the case where I don't know if the winner state actually is in the database or not. Are you suggesting that Grover's algorithm can't be implemented if I am not sure that the database contains my winner state?

Comment: That is really good question. I suppose that resulting state will be equally distributed superpostion as no state is marked and hence there is no change in the phase. But I am not absolutely sure about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will quickly reexplain how Grover's Algorithm works :

- First you put your whole system in an equal superposition. The means, for example, with 3 qubits, that your system will be in the state : $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|000\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|001\rangle+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|110\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|111\rangle$. You will assign one of these basis states for each element of your database.
- Then you run the phase-flip oracle gate : $|U_\omega\rangle$
- You also run Grover's diffusion operator : $|U_s\rangle$
- You repeat the two last steps until the complex amplitude of the state that **corresponds** to the searched element of your database, has a high enough probability to be measured

As you can see you need at least as many basis states as you have elements in your database, because you **assign** an element of you database to each basis set. But since you system **starts** in an equal superposition, every basis state is searchable, as is every element of your database as long as you **link** a basis state to an element of your database.

However, many different questions mix inside yours, for example, if there is more than one correct element, how does the algorithm work ? I hope I could shed some light on the situation !

Comment: Thank you! I thought that searching for a basis state was just a particular case where the database I need to search is the actual basis set for my n-qubit states. But, as you are saying, it doesn't matter if my database contains bit strings, words, images or whatever because in every scenario I end up assigning each element to a basis set that allows me to use Grover's algorithm. Still one thing I don't understand: what if there's the chance my database does not contain the winner element I am looking for? Is Grover's algorithm useless?

Comment: I guess the algorithm will run infinitely, this is why it is always a good idea to set a maximum number of iterations for applying $U_\omega$ and $U_s$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Quantum Associative Memory algorithm which does not require every element to be present in the database:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807053

There are various improvements over it:

- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020025500000578
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-012-1237-0

You mentioned, the same element can be present multiple times.
This can be taken care by the improvement of Grover search:

- https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807027

You can also use a Quantum Counting (existence) algorithm to search the number of solutions prior to running the Grover search (or the above variants).

Comment: I think [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605034v1) is also interesting when considering multiple solutions